# What are the codes to plot scatter graph for Mann-Whitney U test for 3 groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Scatter graph in R software fro Mann-Whitney U test

[image]

[image]

I want agraph like above for my 3 groups of observations. I tried below codes,  but the wilocx test code is showing some error. I'm getting the graph if I do without wilcox test codes. But the graphs are not like how I expect (Image 1). The groups are separate (Imag 2).

```
set.seed(123)
group1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 6.08, sd = 0.43)
group2 <- rnorm(10, mean = 6.06, sd = 0.55)
group3 <- rnorm(10, mean = 6.1, sd = 0.53)

df <- data.frame(
  value = c(group1, group2, group3),
  group = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), each = 10)
)
library(coin)
test12 <- wilcox_test(value ~ Group,
  data = df,
  subset = (Group %in% c("Group 1", "Group 2"))
)
test13 <- wilcox_test(value ~ Group,
  data = df,
  subset = (Group %in% c("Group 1", "Group 3"))
)
test23 <- wilcox_test(value ~ Group,
  data = df,
  subset = (Group %in% c("Group 2", "Group 3"))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point(
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0), 
    size = 3
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    title = "Scatter Plot for Three Groups",
    x = "Group",
    y = "Value"
  )

print(p)
```